# Snowman css challenge, how to put eyes in a head

Tags: html, css

I want to draw snowman. I have the head done, but the eyes won't appear to me. should I use grid or flex ?

`#e1` `#e2` are the eyes and I put them with head circle in a container cnt-head.

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    #container{
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #dd6b4d;
    }
    
    .sman{
        margin: auto; 
    }
    
    #hat{
        background: #0E1F2B;
        width: 30px;
        height: 12px;
    }
    #hat-white{
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 30px;
        height: 8px;
    }
    #hat-long{
        background: #0E1F2B;
        width: 45px;
        height: 4px;
    }
    
    #cnt-head{
        height: 30px;
        width: 45px;
        overflow: hidden; /* This hide the div under another */
    }
    #head{
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: relative;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        top: -5px;
    }
    
    
    #e1{
        height: 8px;
        width: 8px;
        border-radius: 50px;    
        background: #0E1F2B;
    }
    #e2{
        height: 8px;
        width: 8px;
        border-radius: 50px;    
        background: #0E1F2B;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
            <div id="hat-white" class="sman"></div>
            <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
            <div id="hat-long" class="sman"></div>
    
            <div id="cnt-head" class="sman">
                <div id="head" class="sman"></div>
                <div id="e1"></div>
                <div id="e2"></div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Every answer will be good thanks, and is it possible to draw the whole snowman in 1 div? Or at least 3 divs for every body part?

[Current-Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzHYr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the element then select inspect, then in the code hover on your eye div you can see that they are there but below your snowmans head. In this case I would reccomend using a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) on your head to make the eyes start in the top left position inside that div. Plus that you now can remove the div if you dont wanted it.

```css
body{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
#container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #dd6b4d;
}

.sman{
    margin: auto; 
}

#hat{
    background: #0E1F2B;
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
}
#hat-white{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 30px;
    height: 8px;
}
#hat-long{
    background: #0E1F2B;
    width: 45px;
    height: 4px;
}

#cnt-head{
    height: 30px;
    width: 45px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This hide the div under another */
}
#head::before, #head::after{
  content: "";
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    left:12px;
    top:15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #0E1F2B;
    position: absolute;
}
#head::after{
    left:26px!important;
}
#head{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-white" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-long" class="sman"></div>

        <div id="cnt-head" class="sman">
            <div id="head" class="sman"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sidenote: remember to make id's unique:)

Comment: Very useful! but a little bit advanced for me! 
Otherwise what is !important ?

Comment: It overwrites a rule, for example you can see that both eyes got the same code, but i overrite the left position of one eye and push it further to the right. Dont forget to accept one of the other answers that helped you then:)

Comment: Oh and it might look pretty complicated but it's pretty easy to learn, it's very usefull when building figures like this:)

Answer (score 2):

Hope it's work for you !!!

```css
body{height: 100%;width: 100%;}
#container{width: 400px;height: 300px;background: #dd6b4d;}
.sman{
    margin: auto; 
}
#hat{
    background: #0E1F2B;
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
}
#hat-white{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 30px;
    height: 8px;
}
#hat-long{
    background: #0E1F2B;
    width: 45px;
    height: 4px;
}
#cnt-head{
    height: 30px;
    width: 45px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This hide the div under another */
    position: relative;
}
#head{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: -5px;
}
#e1{
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;    
    background: #0E1F2B;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
#e2{
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;    
    background: #0E1F2B;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-white" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-long" class="sman"></div>

        <div id="cnt-head" class="sman">
            <div id="head" class="sman"></div>
            <div id="e1"></div>
            <div id="e2"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background: #dd6b4d;
        }

        .sman {
            margin: auto;
        }

        #hat {
            background: #0E1F2B;
            width: 30px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 185px;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 19;
        }

        #hat-middle {
            background: #0E1F2B;
            width: 30px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 185px;
            top: 16px;
            z-index: 18;
        }

        #hat-white {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            width: 30px;
            height: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 185px;
            top: 8px;
            z-index: 17;
        }

        #hat-long {
            background: #0E1F2B;
            width: 45px;
            height: 4px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 178px;
            top: 28px;
            z-index: 16;
        }

        #cnt-head {
            height: 30px;
            width: 45px;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* This hide the div under another */
        }

        #head {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 177px;
            top: 25px;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        #scarf_Center {
            background-color: rgb(255 156 20);
            position: absolute;
            left: 168px;
            top: 59px;
            width: 65px;
            height: 16px;
            z-index: 15;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            border: 4px solid #dd6b4d;
        }

        #e1_right {
            height: 8px;
            width: 8px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            background: #0E1F2B;
            position: absolute;
            left: 205px;
            top: 40px;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        #e2_left {
            height: 8px;
            width: 8px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            background: #0E1F2B;
            position: absolute;
            left: 185px;
            top: 40px;
            z-index: 4;
        }

        #head_bottom {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            position: absolute;
            left: 164px;
            top: 60px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">   


</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="hat" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-white" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-middle" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="hat-long" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="scarf_Center"></div>
        <div id="e1_right"></div>
        <div id="e2_left"></div>
        <div id="head" class="sman"></div>
        <div id="head_bottom" class="sman"></div>
    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```